# How does "groupinstall" work ? ( How to convert a group-install to a regular multi yum install <package> -y ? )

Tags: yum, repository

I would like data on how to replicate the same exact outcome for

```
yum groupinstall "Printing client"
```

without running that command but rather run

```
yum install <package> -y
```

perhaps multiple times.

i understand i can get the name of each package via

yum groupinfo "Printing client"

but which ones are suppose to be installed given that it lists 3 different categories : Mandatory, Default, and Optional Packages.

how can one know how to install them in a "orderly fashion" using

```
 yum install
```

so that it replicates the same exact outcome as the original

```
 yum groupinstall "Printing client" ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My system is a little dated, Fedora 14, so I don't have that group, but I do have this group "Printing Support", but I believe my examples are still relevant to your question.

As you've already mentioned, you can use the command `yum groupinfo <group name>` to find out what packages are provided by a particular group. As to installing them I would assume that you have to install all the "Mandatory" and "Default" packages. This could be done like so.

The `yum.conf` parameter, `group_package_types` controls which types get installed.

*excerpt `man yum.conf`*

```
group_package_types List of the following: optional, default, mandatory. 
   Tells yum which type of packages in groups will be installed when 
   'groupinstall' is called.   
   Default is: default, mandatory
```

#### Example

You could run these commands to get the list of packages:

*Mandatory*

```
$ yum groupinfo "Printing Support" | paste -s -d ' '| \
        grep -oP '(?<=tory Packages:\s{4}).*(?=Default Packages:\s+)' | \
        sed 's/[\t ]\+/ /g'
cups ghostscript ghostscript-cups
```

*Default*

```
$ yum groupinfo "Printing Support" | paste -s -d ' '| \
        grep -oP '(?<=Default Packages:\s{4}).*(?=Optional Packages:\s+)' | \           sed 's/[\t ]\+/ /g'
bluez-cups cups-pk-helper foomatic foomatic-db-ppds foomatic-filters gutenprint gutenprint-cups hpijs hplip mpage paps printer-filters samba-client system-config-printer system-config-printer-udev
```

You could then store these 2 commands in 2 variables:

```
$ mpkgs=$(yum groupinfo "Printing Support" ....)
$ dpkgs=$(yum groupinfo "Printing Support" ....)
```

And then run `yum` like so:

```
$ yum install -y $mpkgs $dpkgs
```

When you present all the packages to `yum` like this it can figure out the whether the dependencies are met without you having to worry about presenting the correct set of packages during each invoke.

Comment: +1 The only thing I would add is that the group_package_types parameter in yum.conf specifies which packages get installed by groupinstall.